# Trouble with Left Join in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I've three tables `Post`, `PostTagMap` and `Tag`. `PostTagMap` is a junction table for mapping single post with multiple tags. **I'm trying to write a query to pull all the posts belong to a tag name**.

**Post Table**

```
Id    Name

1     Post #1

2     Post #2
```

---

**Tag Table**

```
Id   Name

1     JS

2     CSS
```

---

**PostTagMap Table**

```
Id   PostId   TagId

1       1       1
2       1       2
```

(edited PostTagMap Data to match with the problem in question)

---

```
SELECT P.Id FROM Post P
LEFT JOIN PostTagMap PTM ON P.Id = PTM.PostId
INNER JOIN Tag T ON PTM.TagId = T.Id
WHERE T.Name = ISNULL(@Tag, T.Name)
```

When `@Tag` is `NULL` I'm getting only the details of post id 1 and not 2. What is wrong with the above query?

Tried below as well,

```
SELECT P.Id FROM Post P
LEFT JOIN PostTagMap PTM ON P.Id = PTM.PostId
LEFT JOIN Tag T ON PTM.TagId = T.Id
WHERE T.Name = ISNULL(@Tag, T.Name)
```

The above also not returning post details of 2.

```
SELECT P.Id FROM Post P
LEFT JOIN PostTagMap PTM ON P.Id = PTM.PostId
LEFT JOIN Tag T ON PTM.TagId = T.Id AND T.Name = ISNULL(@Tag, T.Name)
```

Returning everything even passing @Tag as "JS".

Comment: Your inner join is turning your left join in an inner join too.

Comment: Move the `WHERE` and make it part of the `ON`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried all your Query but all are work fine, try this

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/58d90f/15)

every query are work like it should, Maybe the problem isn't the query

```
SELECT P.Id FROM Post P
LEFT JOIN PostTagMap PTM ON P.Id = PTM.PostId
INNER JOIN Tag T ON PTM.TagId = T.Id
WHERE T.Name = ISNULL('Css', T.Name)
```

return only Post 1 as expected not everything

Edit:

I understand your problem now try my Query

```
DECLARE @Tag NVARCHAR(50)
set @Tag = NULL

SELECT P.Id FROM Post P
LEFT JOIN PostTagMap PTM ON P.Id = PTM.PostId
LEFT JOIN Tag T ON PTM.TagId = T.Id
WHERE @Tag IS NULL OR T.Name = @Tag
GROUP BY P.Id
```

Select all `Post` then add `WHERE @Tag IS NULL` in case your `@Tag` is null and other for `T.Name = @Tag` hope it can help

Comment: When @Tag is NULL then it should return everything right? but it returns only post 1

Comment: I think you are right. Working fine in the fiddle. The problem could be something else.

Comment: You can try change ‘Css’ to NULL in my fiddle it will return every post

Comment: One thing I noticed is in your fiddle both posts has tags mapped to it. In my case the second post dont have any tags.

Comment: edited my answer and tried in your fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/83314/5

Comment: The new query works for the null case but when you set @Tag = 'Js' it returns both posts but it should be returning only post 1.

Comment: Edited my answer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/19751/3 and tested all Tag and null case

Answer (score 2):

your problem is

```
WHERE T.Name = ISNULL(@Tag, T.Name)
```

because `T.Name = T.Name` is FALSE when `T.Name IS NULL`

change your where clause in

```
WHERE (T.Name = @Tag) or (@Tag IS NULL)
```

also use both `LEFT JOIN` or inner will filter out rows with no entry in junction table

Answer (score 0):

I run:

```
SELECT P.Id FROM Post P
LEFT JOIN PostTagMap PTM ON P.Id = PTM.PostId
LEFT JOIN Tag T ON PTM.TagId = T.Id
WHERE T.Name = COALESCE(@Tag, T.Name)
```

And when @Tag is NULL it returns me everything.
I don't know if this what you expect.

Here my [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/09069f/17)

Comment: When @Tag is NULL it is not returning post 2 details

Answer (score 0):

Because you use LEFT JOIN with the rows that depend on the `@Tag` condition, you are basically never filtering `Post` records, you *always get all of them*.

It is true that you are selecting additional data from the left joined tables if there are matching rows, but that does not influence which `Post` records are returned.

What you need to do instead:
If @Tag is null - *do not filter*.
Otherwise - *apply the filter, and do it using **inner** joins*:

```
DECLARE @Tag NVARCHAR(50) = 'Js'   -- or NULL

SELECT P.Id FROM Post P
WHERE @Tag IS NULL
OR EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM PostTagMap M
  JOIN Tag T ON M.TagId = T.Id
  WHERE M.PostId = P.Id
  AND   T.Name = @Tag
)
```

Comment: When you set @Tag = 'Js' it returns both posts but it should be returning only post 1

Comment: Totally rewrote my answer, did some tests and this works.